# Floor lamps vs ceiling lamps

Tags: electrical, energy-efficiency, lamp, cost-effective

Is there any difference in cost between floor lamps and ceiling lamps?
If I would prefer the lowest consumption of the 2 which is more suitable?

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear. Please edit your post to add more information about your situation. "More suitable" is a highly subjective thing, especially with what we (don't) know.

Comment: Lamps don't consume energy. Bulbs do. Doesn't matter the configuration if you have the same wattage and number of bulbs in both situations they will consume the same amount.

Comment: Floor lamps consume floor space, ceiling lamps don't. Electrically, it depends on what specific lighting fixtures and/or bulbs you are comparing. But mostly, it's a decorating question / matter of taste / matter of opinion.

Comment: @isherwood: Suitable I meant for lowest consumption. Which is cheaper to use

Comment: Please *edit your post* to add more information....

Comment: @isherwood:Sure but what extra info is needed? I don't know much about these things

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY that's changing.  Now that they make LED emitters that last 50 years, sockets add expense and subtract reliability, so lamp makers are simply soldering in the LEDs and calling it done.

Comment: @Harper I'm calling the emitters bulbs. My point is the style of the fixture doesn't matter. Just the wattage consumed.

Answer (score 1):

A floor lamp is a consumer product sold loose with an electric cord.  It plugs into a receptacle.  It has a light switch on the lamp.  It takes up space, people knock the lamp over and trip over the cord etc.

A ceiling lamp is built into the ceiling with special wiring in the wall and ceiling.  It is expensive to install the wiring, more expensive to buy, and you need a qualified person to install it.  It doesn't take space, nobody knocks it over or turns it off, and when you turn on a light switch, a light comes on.

Every room must have a light switch.  Normally, this light switch operates the ceiling lamp.  However, builders got an exception made in the Electrical Code in order to make houses cheaper: they can omit the expensive ceiling lamp wiring and switch a *receptacle* instead.  The citizen is expected to buy a floor lamp, and plug it into the receptacle, which is always in an inconvenient location.

The problem with this plan is that citizens often abandon the use of the light switch entirely. They switch the lamp off at the lamp.  They don't even use the receptacle and use other lamps switched at the lamp.  Only they know how to turn the lights on.  Visitors (i.e. firemen, EMTs and police) can't turn the lights on.  They fail to search the room for victims, give medical care via flashlight, and just shoot the kid holding a they-can't-see-what.

Answer (score 0):

It depends why you're lighting the room and your room design (ceiling height, wall/ceiling color, furnishings, etc)

If you want enough light near your chair so you can read a book, then you can use a small wattage floor lamp over your chair so you can read there, but that may leave the other side of the room too dark.

If you want to light the entire  room with  bright even light, you could use one bright light in a ceiling fixture that projects even light throughout the room. Alternatively, you could use several smaller lights throughout the room, but unless you place them carefully, they may lose more light due to absorbtion by walls, furniture, etc than a ceiling light that  can project light directly downward without as much stray light being absorbed.  But with multiple lights throughout the room you could choose to only turn some of them on near the part of the room.where you need the light rather than lighting the entire room all the time.

It's really hard to come up with a "one size fits all" guideline.... It really depends on your own use case and room design.

Modern LEDs are so efficient that lighting energy efficiency matters less than it used to, small savings in efficiency translate into very small cost savings. For example, a 16w "100w equivalent" LED running 4 hours a day for a year would cost me around $3.50/year to operate. If I can save 10% through a more optimal lighting  configuration that only saves me 35  cents a year... And if I spent $20 for that more optimal do configuration, I may never recoup the costs.

In my home, I combine a bright (but dimmable) ceiling  light  with floor lamps where I want  more light for reading or other task. I usually use the ceiling  light at less than full brightness and the floor  lamps for more  light in specific areas. Unlike incandescent lights, LEDs​ can be very efficient when dimming.